# Selecting a two digit number as a whole

Tags: list, file, pseudocode

There is a list of values, the first number represents the parent, the second number represents the child. e.g.

1,8

1,9

1,10

2,3

22,8

22,13

This is where I'm having problems. If these values are stored in a file, line by line as shown, how would I select e.g. the no.22? Would I have to split it when it finds the comma or is there a simpler way because it took me a while to figure out line[0] wouldn't work for 2 digit numbers if I read line by line.

Comment: Well in that format you will definitively have to split it at the comma, what else would make sense? Of course you could loop yourself through line[0], line[1], etc. until you encounter the comma … but do you want to go that far “low-level”? Probably not.

Comment: what language is this in? python, for example, has a `split()` function that can split on delimiters (like `, `

Comment: @CBroe Hahaaa yeah true, I need good modularity. xD

Comment: @RBalasubramanian I'm just doing pseudocode, would it be fine if I just say 
like REPEAT extracting i^th character from the line into a check, and 'check' checks if the character is a comma.